# Solr Stopword not working in multilingual application?

Tags: content-search, solr

In our application, I am trying to implement stopword for various language. We are having country wise core index. One of my search, I am fetching search item using Content, Headline and SearchKeyword fields.  Below is my custom search result item model.

```
public class SiteSearchResultItem: SearchResultItem
{
       [IndexField("headline")]
       public string HeadLine { get; set; }

       [IndexField("searchkeywords")]
       public string SearchKeywords { get; set; }
}
```

Content maps to “Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes.SearchResultItem” Property.  I am building filter using predicate builder as below.

```
predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Content.Contains(searchParms.SearchTerm))
                .Or(p => p.Content.Equals(searchParms.SearchTerm))
                .Or(p => p.HeadLine.Contains(searchParms.SearchTerm).Boost(5f))
                .Or(p => p.HeadLine.Equals(searchParms.SearchTerm).Boost(5f))
                .Or(p => p.SearchKeywords.Contains(searchParms.SearchTerm))
                .Or(p => p.SearchKeywords.Equals(searchParms.SearchTerm));
```

I am testing stopword for Portuguese language. So, I have added a stopword “estávamos” in corresponding stopword_pt.txt file. While query through solr admin, it’s working fine. Below are the queries, I have tested.

In sitecore, I have create two item which has title and “menu_title” which points to headline in solr field.

Solr Admin Raw Query:

headline_t_pt:*estávamos brazil*  => Providing no data

headline_t_pt:”estávamos brazil”  => Providing only  Item which has title brazil data

menu_title_t_pt:"estávamos brazil" => Providing only item which has menu title brazil.

## **Query which passed to solr:**

(_content:(*estávamos brazil*) OR _content:("estávamos brazil") OR headline_t_pt:(*estávamos brazil*) OR headline_t_pt:("estávamos brazil")) AND _language:(pt-BR)

So, It’s working fine in solr Admin tool. But in my sitecore application, it’s not excluding those data.

And Also I need what are the fields will be in content property in solr sitecore. It's mapping to "_content" solr field?

Comment: Check the Search log files to see what the actual SOLR query is that Sitecore is sending over.

Comment: Query passed: (_content:(*estávamos brazil*) OR _content:("estávamos brazil") OR headline_t_pt:(*estávamos brazil*) OR headline_t_pt:("estávamos brazil")) AND _language:(pt\-BR)

Answer (score 1):

The _content field is a field which contains the content of ALL your fields. It is NOT language dependent and does not remove stopwords on the solr side- so remove the 
p.Content.Contains(searchParms.SearchTerm))
.Or(p => p.Content.Equals(searchParms.SearchTerm)

predicates.